# Which Protocol to use to control WiFi (esp 32) enabled Led Light

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, iot, home-automation

I am developing a Wifi based Led light (for learning purpose). I have little knowledge about web server, clients, Web protocols. I will be using ESP32 as Controller cum WiFi module.

There are two ways to control Led light over WiFi.

Locally
Remotely // as of now am focusing on locally

Android/iOS app will be handling all the control part (Flutter app)

Which protocols can I use to control Led light, locally?
will set up multiple esp32 at that time its hard to control the device both devices will have different ip

Kindly help!
if anyone give good example it would be helpful

Comment: Personally I use MQTT and a Mosquitto server running on the internet. Then I simply use MQTTPanel on my phone.

Comment: google `esp32 wifi led`

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I recommend Adafruit IO which has an MQTT backend and a nice configurable dashboard frontend, and is free for small environments. I’ve recently moved to my own Mosquitto MQTT broker and Node Red frontend.

Comment: the thing is its not possible to place a server for controlling an led in local network , i want to use my app as a server to contollig all the devices connected to my router

Answer (score 1):

You can use your ESP as a server by the following [code](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html#put-it-together) and then put your DigitalWrite(1, HIGH) line in the code like the following:

```
 String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
 Serial.print(line);
if(line=="ledon")
{
DigitalWrite(1, HIGH);
}
```

and at this point you just can call the following link to turn the led on

```
http://192.168.*.**/ledon
```

or whatever the starting of your ipv4 is.